# BeautifulSoup installation error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I installed Beautiful Soup using pip and after that when I ran it in cmd I am getting the following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\bs4\__init__.py", line 175
  except Exception, e:
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I used pip install beautifulSoup4 to install beautifulSoup Then i ran the python interpreter from cmd and wrote from bs4 import BeautifulSoup and I got the above error

Comment: You need to give the specific command you used to install, and the  entire traceback you're getting, ...and exactly what "I ran it" means in this context.

Comment: Edited please see again

Comment: We'll need the last lines from the traceback too (they're the most important ones). ps: I'm assuming you meant `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, right?

Comment: Only 1 line was missing aaded that too....Nothing else except that was there on cmd..I got a screenshot I can share if you want and yeah i wrote from bs4 import BeautifulSoup(by mistake wrote here beautifulSoup )

Comment: Hmm.. that looks like a bug in bs4 (`except Exception, e:` is indeed a syntax error in Python 3).  In the latest tree it looks like the error has moved to line 183 (http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py#L183), although I'm not too familiar with bzr so I could be wrong...

Comment: So i just let it go?

Comment: That's up to you..  The fix could be as simple as changing `except Exception, e:` to `except Exception as e:`  The BeautifulSoup developers will probably be happy if you submit a bug report, and even happier if you include a fix <wink>.